# Create database backup at Azure portal

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, backup

I want to create DB backup, but at the azure portal, I don't see the "Manage backups" option. Also at the MsSQL management studio, when right-clicking the database and goes "task" I don't see the "Back Up" option.
So can it depend on Azure subscription type?
Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Azure do not support customer-initiated database backup in Azure SQL Database. Backups occur automatically. This is why you do not see the Backup option in SSMS.
The system does it automatically as I mentioned above. The Backups page in the portal  lets you configure retention for existing backups that the system creates.
Please refer the following article.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?tabs=single-database